# Remove or modify inline css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following html from my page builder. I want to remove z-index.

```
<div class="thrv_wrapper thrv-page-section tve-height-update tcb-mp" data-css="tve-u-17f1c45d6a7" id="mcards" style="z-index: 14 !important;">
```

Tried following 3 options but not working :

```
document.getElementById("mcards").removeAttribute("style");
$("#mcards").css({"z-index": "1!important"});
$('#mcards').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: any error showing

Comment: No error if i used $("#mcards").css({"background-color": "red"}); it works

Comment: try to set z-index: unset

Comment: As a workaround you can create css class having z-index as !important and add that class using jquery dynamically. it will override inline css.

Comment: Added this in stylesheet & it removed the whole inline style attribude #mcards {
    position: inherit!important;
}

Comment: check below answer , it removes style attribute, hope it's helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should like this,

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //$("#mcards").css({"z-index": "unset"});
    $('#mcards').removeAttr("style");
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thrv_wrapper thrv-page-section tve-height-update tcb-mp" data-css="tve-u-17f1c45d6a7" id="mcards" style="z-index: 14 !important;">test</div>
```